# Django - Avoiding repetition in forms

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

In order to limit choices to a current user's set, you have to do something like this:

```
class ChoiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ChoiceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['poll'].queryset = Poll.objects.filter(owner=user)

    class Meta:
        model = Choice
```

which can get pretty repetitive depending on the size of the project.. Plus, you end up having to do the same thing for the admin forms. Is it possible to avoid this?

Comment: you can override the default manager to return a filtered queryset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use generic views and define a `get_form` method to add the user to the form's kwargs, then create a custom base form class which accepts an extra `user` kwarg, like so:

### Form

```
class UserModelForm(ModelForm):
    """
    Base form class with user-based FK filtering.
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Filters the queryset on foreign keys to limit to the provided user.
        """
        # Pop the user from the kwargs
        user = kwargs.pop('user')

        # Delegate initilization to super using the remaining args and kwargs
        super(UserModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.prepare_for_user(user)

    def prepare_for_user(self, user):
        """
        Handles user related setup - for use inside __init__ - abstracted
        from __init__ to make testing easier.
        """
        # Get the user's PK
        user_pk = user.pk

        # Filter foriegn key fields to records owned by the user

        # Make a generator of the form's FK fields
        fks = [f for f in self.fields.itervalues() if hasattr(f, 'queryset')]

        # Iterate the FK fields and filter them - you might want to check
        # for something like `if hasattr(field.queryset.model, 'user'):`, etc.
        for field in fks:
            field.queryset = field.queryset.filter(user_id=user_pk)
```

### View

```
class MyView(object):
    """
    A mixin for views.
    """
    def get_form(self, form_class):
    """
    Returns the provided form class, instantiated with the form kwargs,
    adding a user kwarg.
    """
    # Create some form kwargs with the user included
    defaults = {'user': self.request.user}

    # Update the kwargs with the default form kwargs
    defaults.update(self.get_form_kwargs())

    return form_class(**defaults)
```

Comment: Very clean and definitely avoids repetition... I like. Thanks for the help.